# How to continue with Windows batch command execution, even if the previous maven command fails?

Tags: maven, batch-file, jenkins

I am executing the below commands through **Jenkins->Build section->Add build step->Execute Windows batch command** option:

```
echo "Testing job triggered"
call mvn clean test-compile test
echo "Testing job finished"
```

The batch file runs and the test fails which is fine.
Below is some output message displayed in the console:

```
D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium>echo "Testing job triggered"  
"Testing job triggered" 

D:\Java Testing\Selenium Automation\LearningSelenium>call mvn clean test-compile test  
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
.......
```

If the `mvn` command fails, then it does not execute the next echo message i.e. "Testing job finished".

At the end it throws the below message:

```
The batch file cannot be found.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Why it is throwing this message `The batch file cannot be found.` and how to make the next echo command i.e. `"Testing job finished"` to execute even if the previous `mvn` command failed ?

Comment: Are you sure the batch file you posted does even run?

Comment: Yes. The batch file runs. I have posted some output above. It runs the test, and the test fails which is fine, but my aim is to print the echo message "Testing job finished" present after the mvn command, even if the mvn command fails.

Comment: There might be a `pause >nul` at the end of `mvn.bat`. Did you try to press `ENTER`?

Comment: Note: You don't have to define the `test-compile` phase together with the `test` phase. With the latter the former is passed already. See [Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

Comment: I tried a build that fails with your batch commands here and it prints `"Testing job finished"` instead of `The batch file cannot be found.` in the _Console Output_.

Comment: It probably cannot find "mvn". Why not use an actual "inkovke top level maven target" atep. Or use the full path to `mvn / mvnw.cmd/ mvn.bat` and see. Bat shell won't know where mvn tool is by default; verify by `echo PATH` or` set`.

Comment: I used the commands in the below manner and it worked:  `echo "Testing job triggered" & ^
 call mvn clean test-compile test & ^
 echo "Testing job finished"` But still it is throwing the "The batch file cannot be found." in the console message.

Comment: @GeroldBroser: Thanks I will pass `mvn clean test`. The mvn command ran and the build failed which is fine. As mentioned in previous comment, after appending each command with `&`, it is printing "Testing job finished" in the console message. But still it is giving the "The batch file cannot be found." in the console message.

Comment: This error occurs when the parser can't find the currently running batch file anymore (to read the next line). This usually happens, when the file is deleted or the drive gets disconnected during execution. Messing with `%path%` or `%pathext%`shouldn't lead to this message.

Comment: Is there any reason why the batch file is getting deleted ? There is no command in the batch file which will cause it's deletion. Is it getting deleted by the Jenkins ? What shoul be done which will prevent the deletion of the batch file ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&` operator
In windows batch `&` operator is used when we want to run the second command even if the first one fails.
Something like below:

```
echo "Testing job triggered"
call mvn clean test-compile test & echo "Testing job finished"
```

Comment: My batch file is getting deleted and it is throwing the `The batch file cannot be found.` in the console output. Can you help on this issue ?

Comment: Can you check if you have selected the option to clear the workspace before running each job?

Comment: I have not selected any option to clear the workspace...the option "Delete workspace before build starts" is unchecked...